# Avoid new axios request each time vue component is rendered

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, shopify, vue-component

I'm very much new to Vue so please excuse my lack of knowledge here.

1. In one of my (child) components `(Product_Collection.vue)` I make an axios request to get some products from my Shopify store via their GraphQL API:

   ```
   data: () => {
    return {
      products: null
    }
   },
   methods: {
    getProducts: function(){
      // 1. axios code here...
      // 2. ...then assign result to "this.products" data property 
    }
   }
   ```
2. The products are displayed as thumbnails (let's say there's 10 t-shirts). I then click a product to view it in more detail with more product info and images etc (very much an Amazon-like experience).
3. The product is shown on it's own in a `Product_Single.vue` component. So far so good.

But here's the problem...

4. When I click back to the products page `(Product_Collection.vue)` (the page with the 10 t-shirts on) the axios request to the Shopify API gets called again and the component is re-rendered from scratch.

My question is how do I tell Vue to stop fetching the data from the Shopify API each time the component is rendered? Thank you

Comment: You can use `vuex` to store data in check if data is available or not. Only request to get data when data is not pulled. https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/

Comment: This seems like a good idea, and no doubt it would work, but it just seems a bit over-complicated for such a simple problem. I looked into using `<keep-alive>` on the component as this sounds like it was designed for this type of scenario, but it didn't work as I expected — I'm probably not using it correctly to be honest or I've misunderstood its purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want cache-control, which Axios supports with an extension.

https://github.com/kuitos/axios-extensions

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { cacheAdapterEnhancer } from 'axios-extensions';

const http = axios.create({
    baseURL: '/',
    headers: { 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache' },
    // cache will be enabled by default
    adapter: cacheAdapterEnhancer(axios.defaults.adapter)
});

http.get('/users'); // make real http request
http.get('/users'); // use the response from the cache of previous request, without real http request made
http.get('/users', { cache: false }); // disable cache manually and the the real http request invoked
```

Or you could go a more complex route and cache the results yourself into an object, and check if that object exists, but then you'll have to deal with when you want to expire the data in that object.

If you use a cache-control, and cache-control headers and expiry, you can drive all that from the API layer and not have to deal with manually managed stale data in the application.

Comment: This looks promising. It seems ideal for my particular scenario and I'm sure it would work as I need it to, but I can't help thinking that due to my lack of experience with Vue I'm missing something more obvious as to why the component pulls the data from the API every time instead of just reusing the data from the previous render. Maybe I need to educate myself more with `computed` and `watch` and see if they can be put to use here. Thank you

Comment: Even with cache enabled, if you monitor your traffic, it I’ll look like it makes a call, but in reality it’s fetching from the cache. You can use MITM proxy to verify this.

Comment: Ah, that's interesting — so you're saying that it may currently be fetching from the cache as opposed to doing a new HTTP request every time? I'm using Chrome DevTools (Network tab) to monitor the API calls to the Shopify server and it shows what looks like a fresh (non-cached) request each time, but how can I check where the response is *actually* coming from? I'm unfamiliar with MITM proxy; is Chrome DevTools not capable of something similar? Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can see the information in Chrome DevTools as well. Go to the Network Tab, click on the call your interested in and look for `Status Code: 200  (from disk cache)`. If it doesn't say `(from disk cache)`, then check your `cache-control maxage`

Comment: I wasn't aware of the `Status Code: 200 (from disk cache)` thing. That's very useful information, thanks. I also had `Disable cache` selected in DevTools which was causing the preflight `OPTIONS` request method to get sent before _every_ `POST` request. Once I deselected `Disable cache` the `OPTIONS` request method stopped getting sent and just the `POST` request method was logged.

Comment: this answer is self promotional

Comment: @Hybridwebdev I have no association with axios-extensions

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using Vue Router, and hiding the list page, you can try a simple option.

Instead of v-if, use v-show. The component will be hidden and displayed again. It won't be re-created.

Also, where do you call the API? From `created` or `mounted` hook?

Comment: I am using Vue Router unfortunately. Although I do like the idea of just showing/hiding components with `v-if` and `v-show` so maybe I'll reconsider using Vue Router and just use conditional logic to display content.

I was calling the API from the `created` hook btw

Comment: VueRouter does try to reuse same component for the same route. So, you could check which hook you are loading in...

Comment: I did wonder about this — I thought surely Vue Router is smart enough to know that this component was just displayed and therefore just pull it from a cache. Maybe it's because I'm setting the `products` data property to `null` and therefore essentially forcing it to reload?

Comment: Yes. Should be something like that. (Even when route query params change Vue Router uses the same component, and usually, I have to "watch" the props to react to the changes.)

Comment: @BenClarke were you able to figure this out? I'm facing a similar problem and even swapping 'created' to 'mounted', I find my components (like your products), are reloading as I navigate back to the main page.

Answer (score 0):

If You are using GraphQL then there is the Apollo state management way which integrates nicely with graphQL. Check this out: https://dev.to/n_tepluhina/apollo-state-management-in-vue-application-8k0

So instead of rewriting the app with axios and adding vuex in the mixture, maybe Apollo client would be more convenient